# Flutter Http.put to update data coming from api

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a screen a user profile screen with all the user info, in that same screen i have a button that when presses it will send to edit profile screen where the user can change his account info, i get the account info from the api, im trying to use http.put so when the user writes something to update his name and surname and when the user presses the save changes button i want the data to update to what the user wrote, and in the profile screen the data should be updated. Im getting a 415 error message.

```
final editedFirstName = TextEditingController();
  final editedLastName = TextEditingController();

 body: FutureBuilder<Response>(
                future: futureData,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    AccountData data3 = AccountData.fromJson(
                      json.decode(snapshot.data!.body),
                    );
                    updatedFirstName = data3.firstName;
                    updatedLastName = data3.lastName;

                                       child: TextField(
                                        controller: editedFirstName,
                                        //initialValue: updatedFirstName,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                        ),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 17,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        inputFormatters: [
                                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15)
                                        ],
                                      ),

                                      child: TextField(
                                        controller: editedLastName,
                                        //initialValue: updatedLastName,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                        ),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 17,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        inputFormatters: [
                                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15)
                                        ],
                                      ),



  late Future<Response> futureData;
  String? updatedFirstName;
  String? updatedLastName;

  final editedFirstName = TextEditingController();
  final editedLastName = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> putAccountData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
    var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/v1/employees/account';
    final Map payload = {
      "firstName": editedFirstName.text,
      "lastName": editedLastName.text
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.put(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'authorization': authorization ?? basicAuth.toString()
          },
          body: json.encode(payload));
      print(response.body);
    } catch (er) {
      print(er);
    }
  }

                              ElevatedButton(   // button to update changes and navigate to the 
                                                profile screen with the updated data
                              child: const Text(
                                'Save Changes  ✓',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                print(editedFirstName.text);
                                print(editedLastName.text);
                                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const ProfileScreen(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
```

Comment: What error are you having?

Comment: Im having a problem implementing it, and i thing the problem is on how my project is put together, here is the full code https://pastebin.com/9N7bvyXG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ElevatedButton(
   child: const Text(
      'Save Changes  ✓',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
   ),
   onPressed: () async {
      await putAccountData();
      print(editedFirstName.text);
      print(editedLastName.text);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
         context,
         MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const ProfileScreen()),
     );
   },
)
```

Put `putAccountData` outside the build method but in the class like so:

```
      Future<void> putAccountData() async {
         String url = 'some url';
         final Map payload = {
           "firstName": editedFirstName.text,
           "lastName": editedLastName.text
         };
         try {
            final response = await http.put(Uri.parse(url),
               body: jsonEncode(payload));
               print(response.body);
          } catch (er) {}
      }
```

Comment: No sorry its not working, and i had to remove void from the function and add async on onPressed

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Is not working btw here is what i get from the api >> {"id":"2982de0c-7ac4-11ec-90d6-0242ac120003","firstName":"Taulant","lastName":"Fazliu","phoneNumber":"049000000","idNumber":1248092498}, could the problem be at the jsonUpdated

Comment: or do i have to convert to json

Comment: I made an edit, please check it.

Comment: for some reason its still not working

Comment: any idea why ??

Comment: i think the problem was that i forgot to put a header with the basic auth, but even now its putting the 415 error message

Comment: im updating the question